# Vertical Circular Motion Stone Drop From A Plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

The pilot of an airplane flying a vertical circular arc of radius $R$ at a constant speed $v$ drops a stone of mass $m$ at the highest point of the arc with a zero relative velocity relative to him. Describe the trajectory of the stone with respect to an observer on the ground?

Does the stone just fly off horizontally at the initial speed of $v$ OR because there was a centripetal force acting on it prior to release change the trajectory in any way?

Is there a point where the velocity $\vec{v}$ is such that the pilot actually sees the stone rise up?

I can't think of anything other than the trajectory will be equivalent to a rock attached to a string and the cord being cut, but I feel that the vertical circular motion at constant speed might change the trajectory in some way that I am not able to think of.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). It doesn't seem you're missing anything, but you might consider, if you want, posting at the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/) for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the initial velocity of the stone will just be horizontal with speed $v$. Instantaneous velocity at a moment does not depend on what net force is acting on it at this moment.

As for whether the pilot will at a certain moment sees the stone rising up, it depends on $v$ and $R$. Since the downward acceleration of the pilot at an angle $\theta$ (made with the vertical upward direction) is $\frac{v^2}{R}\cos \theta$, and the stone is under downward acceleration $g$, with the same initial vertical velocity, it depends on which one has a larger downward acceleration. For instance, if $\frac{v^2}{R}>g$, then the pilot will see the stone rising just after the release. On the other hand, if $\frac{v^2}{g}\le g$, the pilot will never see the stone rising.